# How to make a double select filter?

Tags: javascript, html

i'm missing something on this code, my goal is to make 2 filter on this table, the select with id="myInput" must be the one who determine the appearing of the table and apply the first filter,that's the js:

```
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables 
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  table.style.display = '';

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

The second one (id="myInput2") should apply an additional filter, hiding the rows who dont match with another column,here's the js:

```
function myFunction2() {
  // Declare variables 
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput2");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[5];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

That's the html code (forget about br and other bad things, i'm just making an integration of existing code)

```
<label>Zona</label> <select id="myInput2" onchange="myFunction2()">
        <option value="">Tutte le zone</option>
    </select> <label>Gruppo</label> 
    <select id="myInput" onchange="myFunction()">

        <option value="">Seleziona un gruppo di categoria</option>
    </select> <br>
    <br>
    <table  id="myTable" style="display: none;">
        <tr  class="header">
            <th>Categoria</th>
            <th>Descrizione</th>
            <th>Classe</th>
            <th>Tariffa</th>
            <th>Zona</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="infoSezioni" items="${outParamInfoSezioni}">
            <tr>
                <td style="display:none;">${infoSezioni.gruppo}</td>
                <td>${infoSezioni.categoria}</td>
                <td>${infoSezioni.descr}</td>
                <td>${infoSezioni.classe}</td>
                <td>${infoSezioni.tariffa}</td>
                <td>${infoSezioni.zonaCens}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

the problem is that:
When i apply 1 of this filters, the other one just doesnt work, how i can fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please review this one

in both filter one and two

```
    //apply filter + checking flag
    if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) < 0 && (!tr[i].dataset.filtered)) {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";        
       //giving flag
        tr[i].dataset.filtered = true;
      }
```

Displaying Table when either input1 & input2 has value:

```
// and myFunction2() as well
function myFunction() { 
  // Declare variables 
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  //remove unnecessary space
  filter = input.value.trim().toUpperCase();
  //return if no value
  if(filter.length > 0) {return;}
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  //displaying table
  table.style.display = 'block';
...
```

Comment: half of solution, with ur code, now i've a right filtering, but if i try to change one of the 2 select one more time the table just disappear

Comment: I am not sure yet, but im curious with display:none ` <table  id="myTable" style="display: none;">`, why?

Comment: Because i've to display that table only if the select of myInput have a value

Comment: so ensure you set `table.style.display = 'block';` or similiar in every function call (`myFunction1()` & `myFunction2()`)

Comment: Why this should change something? (Actually i tried ur suggestion, but i didnt see any change)

Comment: I dont see in your codes you display the table,, or may be i missed it.
in `myFunction()` you have `table.style.display = '';` but not in your `myFunction2()`. I though that was the problem

Comment: tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  table.style.display = '';
Table must be displayed on first change of myInput, so i wrote it only on myFunction()